# sqlite nomem error on integrity check

Tags: sqlite, out-of-memory, database-integrity

I have a embedded system which uses C/C++ api with a compiled version of SQLite v3. I get a `SQLITE_NOMEM` error on `pragma integrity_check(10);`. I asked the underlying system programmer what the applications heap size is and he tells me that the value is 500k. And also there's a SQL vector size of 4096.

What options do I have to get rid of this? Except splitting the databases to multiple ones?

Comment: `pragma integrity_check` is an administrative function that should not be run during normal operation. (And what to you do when the check fails?)

Comment: I'm restoring the backup file on the corrupted database. Now it happens even it's a NOMEM error. I want to fix this.

Comment: Try the pragma on a test db.  Use the sqlite3 command.  Work from there to find what specifically leads to failure.  (It's possible that the SQLite environment is mucked up somehow.)

Comment: It automatically does integrity check on 4 databases, and it only gives NOMEM error on the bigger sized one. I asked for increasing the application heap size. Tomorrow it'll be clear if it's because of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing heap memory size to 1.5M fixed this problem.